# Flickr photo upload does not work with OAtuth1Swift postImage Method

Tags: swift, oauth, flickr, photo-upload

i'm currently facing the Problem that after the OAuth1 process, when i actually want to send the image, flickrapi responds with: No Photo Specified. :

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rsp stat="fail">
    <err code="2" msg="No photo specified" />
</rsp>`

I am using the OAtuthSwift Framework for ios on XCode 10, Swift 4 for this task.

```
oAuthSwift = OAuth1Swift(consumerKey: flickr.apiKey,
                        consumerSecret: flickr.apiSecret,
                        requestTokenUrl: "https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token",
                        authorizeUrl: "https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/authorize",
                        accessTokenUrl: "https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/access_token")

if oAuthSwift != nil {
   oAuthSwift?.authorizeURLHandler = SafariURLHandler(viewController: self, oauthSwift: oAuthSwift!)

   guard let rwURL = URL(string: "iflickr://oauth-callback/iflickr") else {
       return
   }
   let handle = oAuthSwift!.authorize( withCallbackURL: rwURL) { [unowned self] result in
       switch result {
       case .success(let (credential, response, parameters)):
           print(credential.oauthToken)
           print(credential.oauthTokenSecret)

           guard let img = self.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.0) else {
               print ("cant convert image")
               return
           }
           var params = parameters

// Until Here seems everything fine

           self.oAuthSwift!.client.postImage(flickr.uploadEndpoint, parameters: params, image: img) { upResult in
               switch upResult {
               case .failure(let error):
                   print (error)
               case .success(let response):
                   let respData = response.data
                   if let string = response.string {
                       print ("\nRESULT:\n      - \(string)\n")
                      // Here it prints the above described `No Photo Specified`
                   }
               }
           }
       case .failure(let error):
           print(error.localizedDescription)
       }
   }
}
```

I also tried to do the Request by myself and just take the values of the Dictionary provided from the OAuth process (parameters), but then it says something like: No Token were provided..
Can someone Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned from @Clemens Brockschmidt, the image parameter were not correct. OAuthSwift provided standardwise "media" as parameter name, which was not accepted by the flickr upload API.

After recognise this, i changed the parameter name from "**media**" to "**photo**". 
Code is in 
OAuthSwift/Sources/OAuthSwiftClient.swift:multiPartRequest(), line 125
https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift/blob/b8941a23d1584ba17426c312bb957de355341f4a/Sources/OAuthSwiftClient.swift#L125